# JetBrains' "deploy" equivalent in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, deployment, clion, jetbrains-ide

In JetBrains IDEs, like CLion or PyCharm, I can setup "deployment" so that if I right click any local file or directory, I can "deploy" it via SSH into corresponding place on remote server. Correspondence is set up with several "mappings".

It is more comfortable than scp each changed file manually.

Is something similar exist in VSCode?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the [Push](https://github.com/njpanderson/push) extension suite is perfect for this.

It adds similar features such as Upload, Download, and even Compare local and Remote file's. Please search for it from the VS Code extensions list.
You can also configure the different environments.

Here is the context menu when right-clicking on a file:

[image: Right click on file commands]

This is from author's page on GitHub

> Features It currently provides:
>
> Transfer of individual files. Transfer of folders. Queueing (and
> transfer after save bulk). Watching of files within the project. SFTP
> gateway support - connect via an SSH gateway/bastion to your SFTP
> server. ⚡️ Quick setup Push supports many options and configuration
> modes. The most common of which is a single SFTP setup for an active
> workspace. The following steps will help you get set up in no time:
>
> Install Push from the [VS Code extension marketplace][3]. In the command
> palette, choose Create/Edit Push configuration and confirm the
> location (usually your workspace root), then choose the SFTP template.
> Fill in the missing details within the settings file. At minimum, you
> will need a host, username, a password if not using keys, and the root
> path which will contain the workspace files, starting at the root
> defined by the location of the push.settings.jsonc file. You should
> then be able to upload files within the workspace by using the
> explorer menu, title bars, or command palette. For more complete setup
> and configuration details, feel free to read on.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30456483)

Comment: @camille - should i post the source code of extension from GitHub here?